# Xcode auto-detects a UTF16-LE file as UTF8 on import

Tags: xcode, utf-8

Context: 
My iOS project's source control happens on a proprietary package in Linux, when a new drop arrives I pick the project files and ftp them to my Mac and work with Xcode.

Issue:
A resources file for error messages with UTF16-LE encoding is recognized by Xcode as UTF8 file. "Text Settings" for the file shows "Detected - Unicode (UTF-8)" when the files are opened in Xcode. Project build fails with error message "corrupted file". The file is also referenced by other projects in the same workspace and build fails there with error "Read failed: The data couldn't be read because it has been corrupted."

Workaround:
When I manually change the encoding to UTF16-LE (Re-interpret), my base project works fine. For the other projects in the workspace I need to convert the file to UTF16-LE to get it working.

Question:
Can I avoid the workaround and make Xcode recognize the encoding automatically ?

p.s: The file's encoding is in xcodeproj file is "fileEncoding = 2483028224" and handled elsewhere as a binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 2 chars of the file are used to identify the file encoding. In this case it was not reflecting what it was. After correcting it, Xcode seems to recognize it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic encoding detection is [extremely fragile process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) based on heuristics and it cannot ever work well. It is mainly meant to give some convenience for computer-illiterate people who are not even aware that such a thing as encoding even exists, and so are not capable of explicitly declaring it.

For others we have the convenience of being able to know and explicitly declare encodings, and thus always get it right. The program you are using should have a capability in configuration and settings to explicitly declare an encoding, so you don't have to rely on the voodoo that is automatic encoding detection.